# Visual Studio 2008 - Can't edit events in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I just got a new PC with Windows 7.  While editing a WPF window, when I right-click on a control and select Properties, I get the familiar property window docked in the lower-right coner.  For some reason, I do not see the lightning bolt button to toggle over to the events.  Also, when I double-click on a control, nothing happens.

Has anyone seen this?  What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually uninstalled VS 2008 (by uninstalling each component one-by-one as specified in the readme file), then reinstalled it along with SP1, and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install VS 2008 SP1 for that feature (and a lot more!).

Comment: What do you mean by that? You installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and still it did not show up? Now, I assume you know NetFx3.5SP1 and VS2008SP1 are different.

Comment: Yes, the events button still does not show up, and yes, I have SP1 installed for both .NET 3.5 and VS2008.